# sdk paypal and express checkout paypal

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

There's something confusing me when I used this [sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php). I create payment and successfully submitted to my merchant account using that [sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php). Using this [sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) returns a lot of functions like payment history list. But what makes me confuse is that I create payment transaction using the api of express checkout and successfully submitted to my merchant account. I used this code to see the payment list that I received from express checkout.

```
$info = 'USER=xxxxx'
        .'&PWD=xxxx'
        .'&SIGNATURE=xxxxx'
        .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
        .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
        .'&STARTDATE=2014-04-08T05:38:48Z'
        .'&ENDDATE=2014-07-14T05:38:48Z'
        .'&VERSION=94';

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$result = explode("&", $result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

This returns the payment list but never returns the payment that I made using that sdk. When I check the payment history of that sdk. It only returns the payment list that I made using that sdk and disregard the payment list that I made using Express Checkout. Why is it I never get the whole payment list? So far I have no problem about the code of sdk. Looks good for me, only the returns that I confused between this [sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) and express checkout api.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a couple of things:

- Exclude the ENDDATE parameter
- Set TRANSACTIONCLASS to ALL
- Make sure the version of the two different SDKs (it reads like you're using 2 different code bases?) is the same